# How do I fix the 404 page with my Java app?

Tags: java, maven

My project works perfect locally but when deploying to a live server, I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access '/connect'. Any help would greatly be appreciated as I'm new at this language. Here is what my web.xml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ConnectController</servlet-name>
    <display-name>ConnectController</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>com.hyperx.web.ConnectController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConnectController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/connect</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is the class path and code:

[image]

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hyperx</groupId>
  <artifactId>trustpilot-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>trustpilot-app Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.eclipsesource.minimal-json</groupId>
       <artifactId>minimal-json</artifactId>
       <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>trustpilot-app</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I can see that your IDE is displaying some error at the package declaration. On a side note, you do not need to declare these things in `web.xml`. You can simply use `@WebServlet("/connect")` just before `public class ConnectController` declaration.

Comment: I see. I've removed the mappings in the web.xml and added that but I'm still getting a 404.

Comment: How are you running it locally vs. live server?

Comment: What's the server you are using for live? What file you deploy to it, share complete name. What is the complete local url that is working and complete url that is giving 404 error?

Comment: I appreciate all the help.  So the server is a linux server. The file name is trustpilot-app. Here is the full path to where I'm trying to view: http://hyperxdemo.com/trustpilot-app/connect. Going to just http://hyperxdemo.com/trustpilot-app will give me my test page but it's just a basic index.jsp...not a servlet like the /connect url is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed hosting providers for this and it worked perfectly. Must have been something related to that server config.  Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to diagnose the problem without more information. Are you using maven to build the application (there is `pom.xml`)? Show the `pom.xml` content. The IDE reports a problem on package level - most probable cause is that `src/main/java` is not a source folder. Which indicates that maven is not building a war. I would suggest to extract the build artifact (war) and see if the `com.hyperx.web.ConnectController` class is there. Check the log files of the web server to see if the deployment is successful.

Comment: I've updated the my original post with the pom.xml.  I do see the ConnectController.class in the correct folder (WEB-INF/classes/com/hyperx/web/ConnectController.class). Not sure how to check logs other than the console logs. Are there logs when you build a WAR file? Also, I am using Magen.

Comment: What server are you using? Tomcat? Do you try to open `http://localhost:xxx/trustpilot-app/connect`

Comment: Yes, Tomcat.  I can run the app locally just fine using http://localhost:8080/trustpilot-app/connect.  But when going live it shows a 404 (http://hyperxdemo.com/trustpilot-app/connect).

Comment: Basically you need to get the log files from live server and check if there is an exception during deployment. If you have ssh access the logs are usually located at `$CATALINA_BASE/logs` where `$CATALINA_BASE` is the base directory of tomcat instance.